# debian : mount /var as overlayfs at boot

Tags: debian, systemd, tmpfs, overlayfs

I'm trying to mount `/var` with an overlayfs (with a tmpfs) at boot but don't manage to make it works.

Here is what I've done :

```
# creating tmpfs
mkdir /var.tmpfs
mount -t tmpfs -o rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,size=512m,mode=0775 tmpfs /var.tmpfs
chmod -R u=rwX,g=rX,o=rX /var.tmpfs

# creating overlay
mkdir /var.tmpfs/{work,upper} /var.overlay
mount -t overlay -o rw,lowerdir=/var,upperdir=/var.tmpfs/upper,workdir=/var.tmpfs/work overlay /var.overlay
chmod -R u=rwX,g=rX,o=rX /var.overlay

# binding to /var
mount --bind /var.overlay /var

# filling /etc/fstab
[...]
tmpfs           /var.tmpfs      tmpfs   rw,nosuid,noatime,size=512m          0  0
overlayfs       /var.overlay    overlay rw,lowerdir=/var,upperdir=/var.tmpfs/upper,workdir=/var.tmpfs/work    0   0
/var.overlay    /var            none    bind    0   0
```

When the system boot I face the following error :

```
overlayfs: failed to resolve '/var.tmpfs/upper' -2
```

Which is normal since tmpfs is empty when mounted.

- How to create `upper` and `work` directories at boot

  - after mounting /var.tmpfs
  - before mounting /var.overlay
- Or is there any other solution with directories already present at boot ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The folders `/var.tmpfs/upper` and `/var.tmpfs/work` are located in tmpfs and will no longer present after reboot.

One option is to create both of them in fstab.

Answer (score -1):

I do something similar with https://github.com/StuartIanNaylor/zram-config but use zram rather than tmpfs.

I bind mount the target directory somewhere else.
Create and mount zram and mkdir overlayfs dirs.
Then mount the overlay

```
mount --verbose --types overlay -o lowerdir=$BIND_DIR,upperdir=/opt/zram$RAM_DEV/upper,workdir=/opt/zram$RAM_DEV/workdir overlay $ZRAM_DIR
```

$ZRAM_DIR is the target dir that gets bind mounted elsewhere so on stop I can sync changes.
Rather than the complete /var you might have to just add a collection of lowerdir as maybe tmpfs over tmpfs is not working and really why?